# Capture pipe, comma, and whitespace delimiteres with regex

Tags: python, regex

Brand new to Python. I'm using the `csv` reader to parse some files. I'm going to parse info that uses 3 different delimiters. A comma, a pipe, and whitespace (for now).

I have this:

```py
    with open(filepath, "r") as fp:
            file_lines = fp.readlines()
            delimiter = re.search("\w+([^\w])", file_lines[0]).group(1)
            reader = csv.reader(file_lines, delimiter=delimiter)
            print('Delimiter: [{}]'.format(delimiter))
            line_list = [row for row in reader]
            print(line_list)
```

This works with my `comma.txt` file. But when passing in my `pipe.txt` file, it's capturing the whitespace before grabbing the actual pipe.

sample input of a row with pipes would look like this:

Pipes: `Bouillon | Francis | G | M | Blue | 6-3-1975`

Whitespace: `Bouillon Francis G M Blue 6-3-1975`

Commas: `Bouillon, Francis, G, M, Blue, 6-3-1975`

Would you guys recommend another approach? Or should I just alter my regex instead?

Comment: Well, the first non-word character is a space in your example, so it works as intended. ;) Just `re.search` your regex manually on that line and you'll see.

Comment: So, that `delimiter` variable would be one char. I'm just passing it into `csv.reader`. The goal would be that if opens a `comma.txt` file and finds a comma, it captures it and passes it as a delimiter. Same with a `pipe.txt` file, and with a whitespace.

Comment: Assuming your input doesn't have any pipes in the content (but then it might have commas), and content separated with commas might have whitespace, and content with whitespace doesn't have any former separator, you have a hierarchy that you can check from top to down. But with regex you would literally find first character that matches - here a space that is *not* a delimeter.

Comment: @h4z3 Yup, that's correct. I have to figure out how to make it work when it's capturing a group like `Johnny,` and `Johnny |`.

Comment: Again: `Bouillon | Francis` has spaces between content and separator. As I said, then first catch is a space, not a pipe. Is this a valid example or is it `Bouillon|Francis` (no spaces)? Because as I said, that space is what gets caught and the approach will change depending on that.

Comment: Re-reading what you wrote, the pipe input will always have whitespace before the pipe. So, yes I think the approach would have to more hierarchical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comments, the regex works as intended. ;)

`Bouillon | Francis | G | M | Blue | 6-3-1975` with `\w+([^\w])` gets `'Bouillon '` as `group(0)` (full match) because the space IS the first non-word character. ;)

If you want to keep padding spaces in your data or your data might contain whitespace (e.g. `Name Surname|Age`), then you can't search for whitespace in the same regex as searching for pipes and commas - because that padding or a space in first value will get caught.

(Unless you search for more than one character in that regex, but then you need more complex code and I like simplicity and readability. ;) )

What you can do is:

1. Search for pipe and comma (assuming pipe-separated content has no commas and comma-separated content has no pipes). Assume whitespace only if the search failed.

```
search = re.search(r"[|,]", file_lines[0]) # add other delimeters in square brackets
# we don't have capturing groups, our full catch (group 0) is first character that matches possible delimeters
separator = search.group(0) if search else " " # is search was empty, assume space
```

2. Another approach is by hierarchy.

   - Assume pipe-separated file can have anything in the content (including commas - as opposed to first approach - and whitespace)
   - Assume comma-separated file can have anything but pipes in the content
   - ...
   - Assume whitespace-separated file have no characters used as possible separators

   Then the check would need to be hierarchical: you first check for any existence of pipes. If there are not any, check for commas. If there are not any, check for ... If there are not any, assume space.

   This can be implemented as a simple for-loop and your possible delimeters can be a simple string, from the most important separator - `"|,"`. Regexes are bad for such simple things. ;)

```
possible_separators = "|,"
separator = " "
for sep in possible_separators:
    if sep in file_lines[0]:
        separator = sep
        break
```

Comment: Thanks! I took your first approach since it seems more readable to me. One last question. Would it be worthy making this a seperate function?

Comment: My approach to separate functions is: if I reuse this code (or very similar) somewhere, or if I might want to find this snippet later, I do a function. Or if my current function grows too much, I try to break it up in smaller chunks (kinda S from SOLID - small chunks, possibly testable or replaceable). And doing it pythonic way - keep things readable. But I'm just a junior programmer that writes scripts, not big applications, so approaches may differ. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [`csv.sniffer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) class to determine the dialect of csv you are about to parse.

The `sniff()` function takes a string of potential delimiters which it will use to try and determine how to parse the file. It's pretty smart, but the fact that your potential delimiters include a space and your `|` files haves spaces is a problem for it. If you pass `delimiters=',| '` with a space it will identify the space as the delimiter for files delimitied with `|`. One options is to try with the non-space delimiters and if that fails try with spaces:

```
import csv
with open('test_space.csv') as csvfile:
    try:
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024), delimiters=',|')
    except:
        csvfile.seek(0)
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024), delimiters=' ')
    dialect.skipinitialspace = True
    csvfile.seek(0)

   reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
    for line in reader:
        print(list(map(str.strip, line)))
```

This will correctly identify rows like this as space-delimited:

```
Bou|illon Francis G M Bl,ue 6-3-1975
Bouillon Francis G M Blue 6-3-1975
Bouillon Franc,is G M Blue 6-3-1975
```

which will be quite difficult to handle with regex approach.

But if you have potential delimeters in every row it looks at, it will match those. For example, it parses this as comma-delimited (I assume because it sees a comma in each row):

```
Bou|illon Francis G M Bl,ue 6-3-1975
Bou,illon Francis G M Blue 6-3-1975
Bouillon Franc,is G M Blue 6-3-1975
```

Comment: We've all been trying to reinvent the wheel. It's nice to know such thing as Sniffer exists! Do you know how "pretty smart" is really smart? - Does it take the first matching delim or does it seeks the most common character from those delims (both approaches would break on space)?

Comment: It's not flawless. I would not expect it to work if you have tons of potential delimiters in your columns, but it correctly identifies: `Bou|illon Francis G M Bl,ue 6-3-1975\nBouillon Francis G M Blue 6-3-1975` as a space delimited file, but it will try hard to make the first sniff work, so if you have commas in every row it will think it's a delmiter. It would be a much easier problem without the space-delimited files.

Comment: I have now read your added examples and your comment. :) Thank you! It seems like it looks for a delim that have a same/similar number in each line (the latter example with commas).

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, I would go for someting like

```
([^\w-]|[|]|[,])
```

If you trim that, you will get your delimiters. Have a look at [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to test your files. It's JavaSript regex, but I found it useful for debugging Python regex as well.

**EDIT**

as @h4z3 pointed out correctly, you can simplify:

```
([^\w-]|[|,])
```

Comment: `[|]|[,]`? You know the `[]` already works as a single character from the group, right? ;) So this part should only be `[|,]`.

Comment: I noticed. I said it was from the top of my head ;-) I like to test my regexes and then optimize them down. The other way round takes much more time IMHO.

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately, the input will always have a space before a pipe. So this would still capture the whitespace first.

Comment: user7496931. Yep. Quick and dirty, but as suggested, you can run `strip()` on whatever you captured to get rid of any whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

**2** approaches:

(you may also proceed without `csv.reader`, just split by `sep` with trailing spaces)

Sample files:

*pipe.txt:*

```
Bouillon | Francis | G | M | Blue | 6-3-1975
a | b | c | d | f | g
```

---

*comma.txt:*

```
Bouillon , Francis , G , M , Blue , 6-3-1975
a , b , c , d , f , g
```

---

*space.txt*

```
Bouillon   Francis   G   M   Blue   6-3-1975
a   b   c   d   f   g
```

---

```
import csv
from itertools import chain

with open('pipe.txt') as f:
    line = next(f).strip()   # extracting the 1st line
    sep = re.search(r'^\w+([\s\|,]+)', line).group(1)
    sep = ' ' if sep.isspace() else sep.strip()

    reader = csv.reader(chain(iter([line]), f), delimiter=sep, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

The output (for file `comma.txt` and `pipe.txt`):

```
['Bouillon ', 'Francis ', 'G ', 'M ', 'Blue ', '6-3-1975']
['a ', 'b ', 'c ', 'd ', 'f ', 'g']
```

---

```
with open('space.txt') as f:
...
```

The output for `space.txt` is more cleaner due to `skipinitialspace=True` feature:

```
['Bouillon', 'Francis', 'G', 'M', 'Blue', '6-3-1975']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
```

---

Or without `csv.reader`:

```
with open('comma.txt') as f:
    line = next(f).strip()
    sep = re.search(r'^\w+([\s\|,]+)', line).group(1)
    pat = re.compile(sep)

    for row in chain(iter([line]), f):
        print(pat.split(row.strip()))
```

The output:

```
['Bouillon', 'Francis', 'G', 'M', 'Blue', '6-3-1975']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
```

Enjoy!